# How to insert a JComboBox in to a JTextPane at caret position?

Tags: java

I want to insert a ComboBox in JTextPane when I press Ctrl+ Space as NetBeans's suggestions, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

First you would need to use `Key Bindings` to define the `Action` to invoke when the Ctrl+Space key is pressed. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

Next you would want to create an `Action` by extending `TextAction` to add the combo box to the text pane. The basic code might be something like:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
comboBox.addItem("one");
comboBox.setSize( comboBox.getPreferredSize() );
Rectangle location = textPane.modelToView( textPane.getCaretPosition() );
comboBox.setLocation(location.x, location.y);
comboBox.setSize( comboBox.getPreferredSize() );
textPane.add( comboBox );
```

Finally, when the combo box loses focus you would need to remove the combo box from the text panel.